# Continuous random variable with mixed density function

Tags: probability, continuity, random-variables

I am having trouble with finding P(X=1). I am not sure how you would find this since 1 is not included. Also, I believe my cdf is wrong since they do not add up to 1.

The problem states, A continuous random variable defined on the interval [0,2] has the following mixed density function:

f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x &\text{if } 0 \leq x<1\\
\frac{-1}3 x + \frac{2}3 &\text{if } 1< x \leq 2
\end{cases}

Use the Law of Total Probability to find P(X=1).

I found the cumulative distribution function by integrating the mixed density function that was provided.

F(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}2 &\text{if } 0 \leq x<1\\
\frac{1}6 &\text{if } 1< x \leq 2
\end{cases}

1 = P(X=1) by the law of total probability, but wouldn't P(x=1) = 0 since 1 is not included.

Comment: To begin with, your PDF f(x) does not integrate to 1.

Comment: How would I set up the integration? I thought I have to integrate from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 2.

Comment: @Meg, your PDF is integrate to $\frac12+\frac16\neq 1$. So this is not PDF. Moreover, if the distribution as absolutely continuous, then $\mathbb P(X=1)=0$. And finally, CDF $F(x)\neq P(X=x)$. Check your question.

Comment: If I'm understanding the meaning of the term "mixed density function" correctly here, it sounds like $X$ is meant to be distributed according to a distribution with partially discrete and partially continuous properties. In this case, there is a concentration of nonzero probability at exactly $X = 1$, with the remaining probability distributed continuously according to the given distribution. Since the given continuous part of the PDF integrates to $2/3$, that leaves a probability of $1/3$ to be concentrated at $X=1$. So $P(X=1) = 1/3$.

Comment: @JohnBarber This will not undo the fact that the OP does not understand what is he doing.

Comment: @JohnBarber Moreover, Take a mixture of $2/3$ of absolutely continuous distribution with PDF $$\frac32\begin{cases}
x &\text{if } 0 \leq x<1\\
\frac{-1}3 x + \frac{2}3 &\text{if } 1< x \leq 2
\end{cases}$$ and $\frac13$ of degenerate at $0$ distribution, and you will get the same PDF of absolutely continuous component as in the question, but $\mathbb P(X=1)=0$.

Comment: @NCh I'm not sure I follow you. I think the mixed distribution you describe there wouldn't work because the continuum portion of it already includes $0$ since it says $0\leq x < 1$. I believe the distribution of $X$ in the original post is implied to be:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{1}{3} \delta(x-1) \;+\;
\begin{cases}
x & 0 \leq x < 1\\
-\frac{1}{3}x + \frac{2}{3} & 1 < x \leq 2
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: @JohnBarber I do not know, what is "continuum portion". But I know that the integrals will not change if we change integrand in few points. Therefore the distribution with "PDF" $$\begin{equation} f(x) = \frac{1}{3} \delta(x-0) \;+\; \begin{cases} x & 0 \leq x < 1\\ -\frac{1}{3}x + \frac{2}{3} & 1 < x \leq 2 \end{cases} + 0\cdot\delta(x-1) \end{equation}$$ has exactly the same absolutely continuous component as is given in the question.

Comment: @NCh I suspect the question thinks you cannot have a $\frac{1}{3} \delta(x-0)$ term since that might suggest something like infinite density at $x=0$, when the question says $f(0)=0$

Comment: @Henry If we suspect a mixture of absolutely continuous distribution and discrete distribution, there is no difference, what is the value of the first component PDF in distinct points.